# error: $pkgauxdir is not a directory: '@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/libtool/2.4.6_2/share/libtool/build-aux'

Tags: linux, docker, homebrew, centos7

when i run `brew install opencv@2`,i got an error like this

```
error: $pkgauxdir is not a directory: '@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/libtool/2.4.6_2/share/libtool/build-aux'
```

and my .bash_profile

`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin`
and i confirm i have directory `/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_2/share/libtool/build-aux`, so how to fix this error

enviroment dockerfile built form centos7 user: zcl

i checkout `.bash_profile` and directory,
i wonder 
`@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@`,
how to get homebrew path

i want to install successed

Comment: you get this error when you run inside a docker container? and in that docker container you have `/home/local/Cellar...`?

Comment: yes, in a docker container, and i `exec -it --user zcl` attach the container,  and i have `/usr/local/Cellar` dir, but not found `/home/local/Cellar`, and found `/home/zcl/.linuxbrew/Cellar`

Comment: but on my imac, i installed brew and opencv@2 successed. and i found `usr/local/Cellar` but not found `/home/local/Cellar`

Comment: when i run `which -a brew` it  echo `~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew`,

Comment: when i run `brew config`
echo

- HOMEBREW_PREFIX: `/home/zcl/.linuxbrew`
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: `/home/zcl/.linuxbrew/Cellar`
- HOMEBREW_CACHE: `/home/zcl/.cache/Homebrew`
- HOMEBREW_LOGS: `/home/zcl/.cache/Homebrew/Logs`
- HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: `/home/zcl/.linuxbrew/Homebrew`
- HOMEBREW_SYSTEM_CURL_TOO_OLD: 1
- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Comment: brew stuff works with Mac, not with centos7. You need to install the approp software in your docker container by adding `RUN yum xxx` to your dockerfile for your image.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. One solution I found recommended reinstalling libtool (**brew reinstall libtool**) but that didn't help. What worked for me was actually **Xcode** itself. I relaunched **Xcode** and it did an self upgrade (downloading components?). I then checked **Xcode Preferences** and the **Command Line Tools** in **Locations** wasn't set. After that, the problem went away.